# How to use Find() here: Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some menu. The menu property is in data()

Like this:

```
buttonMenu: [{
        id: 1,
        isActive: true,
        title: 'Payment Method ID'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        isActive: false,
        title: 'Payment Method Title'
      }
]
```

Printing these menus with `v-for`

Like this:

```
<ul class="ulOrder">
   <li
      v-for="(btnMenu, index) in buttonMenu"
         :key="index"
         class="filter-item float-left"
         :class="{ 'active-class' : btnMenu.id == isActive }"
         @click="changeActive(btnMenu.id)"
      >
      {{ btnMenu.title }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to print the Menu Title in another place, which is now active.

I am trying with method:

```
changeActive(id) {
      console.log(id)
      this.isActive = id

      let item = this.buttonMenu.find((item) => item.id = id)
      this.subTitle = item.title
}
```

But it is giving me error. And Both are active!!!!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Actually there is no error. But when I am clicking on second menu it is not changing the status. Always 2 is showing after clicking on 2. In console.log(id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `=` to `==`.

```
let item = this.buttonMenu.find((item) => item.id == id)
```

Comment: Yes. That was the error!!!

Answer (score -1):

Please checkout the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xc7L8be/)

```
changeActive(id) {
  console.log(id)
  this.isActive = id

  let item = this.buttonMenu.find((item) => item.id === id) // use `===` in place of `=`
  this.subTitle = item.title
 }
```